# Linq to Sql Group By Class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, group-by

I would like to pass a groupedList to several functions, however I'm getting strange results when trying to group by using a class rather than an anonymous type. In the following example the anonymous type returns 2 results, as expected, but the concrete class returns 5, as if it wasn't even grouped.

The Question: Is it possible to do Linq to Sql Group By with concrete classes?

```
public class person
{
    public string Name;
    public string State;
}

public class personGroup
{
    public string State;
    public personGroup(string personState)
    {
        State = personState;
    }
}


void Main()
{   
    var people = new List<person>();
    people.Add(new person {Name = "Bob", State = "Tx"});
    people.Add(new person {Name = "Bill", State = "Tx"});
    people.Add(new person {Name = "Tracy", State = "Tx"});
    people.Add(new person {Name = "Steve", State = "Md"});
    people.Add(new person {Name = "Kelly", State = "Md"});

    var groupedPeople = people.GroupBy (p => p.State );
    groupedPeople.Count().Dump();//Returns 2

    var morePeople = people.GroupBy (p => new personGroup(p.State) );
    morePeople.Count().Dump();//Returns 5
}
```

Comment: There is no "SQL" in this question.  I think you just mean LINQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `GroupBy` method uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to compare the items in question when a custom `IEqualityComparer` is not provided (you did not provided one).  This will be based on the implementation of `IEquatable<T>` of the type `T` in question, if there is one, and if not, then it will simply use `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode` of that type.

Your custom type does not provide any implementation whatsoever, it relies entirely on the implementations defined in `object`, which, for a reference type, is based on the reference of the object.  Each of the `personGroup` objects you created have a different reference, and so are different.

Anonymous types don't use that default equality behvaior; they override the definition of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to be dependent on the identity of each of the properties they represent.

If you want to use your own custom type to group on, and the default equality semantics aren't what you want, you'll need to either provide a custom `IEqualityComparer` implementation, or override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the type in question.

Comment: I see how to override for Equals, but what would I use for GetHashCode, does it need to be unique for each group, or can I just return 1.GetHashCode

Comment: @SumGuy Read the documentation for the method to see what guidelines you need to follow when implementing it.  In this specific case you likely only need to return the hash code of the `State` that the group is wrapping, but in more complex situations you may have to do something more involved to generate a good hash.

Answer (score 3):

In your second group by, there are 5 groups because the key is always different. `personGroups` are compared by reference, and all of the objects have different references.You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your `personGroup` class to compare your instances based on State, or implement an [`IEqualityComparer<personGroup>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass it to [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534334(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: how do you pass it to the GroupBy?

Comment: `people.GroupBy (p => new personGroup(p.State), new MyEqualityComparer() )`

Answer (score 2):

As Servy has stated above you need to create a custom IEqualityComparer of type PersonGroup in order for your example to work.

I've run into this a lot myself so I created a generic EqualityComparer that will work with any model (that uses properties)!

```
/// <summary>
/// Given two models, return TRUE if all the properties are equal,
/// else return FALSE
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TModel">Type of the models being compared</typeparam>
public class PropertyEqualityComparer<TModel> : IEqualityComparer<TModel>
{
    public bool Equals(TModel x, TModel y)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TModel).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (!Object.Equals(prop.GetValue(x), prop.GetValue(y)))
            {
                return false;
            }    
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TModel obj)
    {
        int hash = 1;
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TModel).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            hash ^= prop.GetValue(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

With this class you will be able to do what you what.

```
// NOTE: Use properties instead of public variables
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

// NOTE: Use properties instead of public variables
public class personGroup
{
    public string State { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{   
    var people = new List<Person>();
    people.Add(new Person{Name = "Bob", State = "Tx"});
    people.Add(new Person{Name = "Bill", State = "Tx"});

    var morePeople = people.GroupBy(p => new PersonGroup{State = p.State}, new PropertyEqualityComparer<PersonGroup>());
    morePeople.Count();
}
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, but it doesn't handle null values. This can be achieved by changing the code inside the `foreach` inside the `GetHashCode` method. Something like `var value = prop.GetValue(obj); if (value == null){ hash ^= -1; continue; } hash ^= value.GetHashCode();` should fix the problem.